# Directly accessing an instance variable vs. Using an accessor method

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, accessor

Can anyone explain the difference between accessing an instance attribute via `self.attribute` and by `@attribute`?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`self.attribute` calls the method `attribute`.
`self.attribute = value` calls the method `attribute=` with the argument `value`.
`@attribute` and `@attribute = value` get/set the value of the instance variable `@attribute`.

So basically they're two entirely different things.

However if you call `attr_accessor :attribute` it defines the method `attribute` to return `@attribute` and the method `attribute=(value)` to set `@attribute = value`. So in that case, there is no difference.

Comment: Note that it is generally recommended to use `self.` (unless you're writing the getter/setter method) even if you _currently_ have `attr_accessor`. This protects you from additional refactor work and bugs if you later change the accessor method(s) to do more than just get/set the instance variable. (Or if someone else patches or subclasses your work.)

Comment: One of the bugs Phrogz is talking about is if you simply call attribute = _____ instead of self.attribute = ______ you are setting a local variable instead of the instance variable.

Answer (score 3):

"Accessing instance variable directly is about two times faster than accessing them with accessor methods"

Check out the: https://www.greyblake.com/blog/2012-09-01-ruby-perfomance-tricks/

Comment: The link is broken. This one works: https://www.greyblake.com/blog/2012-09-01-ruby-perfomance-tricks/